# Is this signal BFSK or BPSK?

Tags: digital-modes, modes, hackrf, spectrum-analyzer

I'm trying to analyse a signal from a HVAC remote control (864 MHz) with my HackRF, but I'm facing an interrogation about the used modulation:

- Is it **BFSK** (frequency modulation) or **BPSK** (phase modulation) ?

Here's what the signal looks like, once visualised from the HackRF raw data:

*(with both *I* and *Q* waveforms, each one shifted from 90°)*

[image: BFSK-OR-BPSK]

**NB:** I can notice two different frequencies but sometimes it looks like both are shifted apart from 90° between transitions. Or maybe the ratio *(bit width / modulation period)* is really low in this example?

Here is a zoom on a part of the sample that gave me headaches:

[image: BFSK-OR-BPSK-ZOOM]

> **EDIT: Like pointed out in the comments, the question was missing a lot of information and visualisation about the signal. Thanks for helping me guys... here is more:**

**Spectogram along time:**

[image: FFT-visualisation]

**Zoom-in part of the first "symbols" with FFT, Amplitude, Phase and Frequency**

[image: FFT-details]

**FFT visualisation with max detection enabled (under GNU radio companion, with a DC blocker):**

I've recorded the samples close to the signal frequency, I realised I might have done something wrong...

[image: FFT-peak-hold]

**Constellation plot (under GNU radio companion, with a DC blocker):**

[image: constellation]

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Thanks a lot @rclocher3 !

Comment: Perhaps your answer is on [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bpsk+fsk), and would be better asked there.

Comment: Trying to understand a signal by looking at a time-domain plot of the I and Q components is like trying to find a driving route by looking at the SVG source of a map.

Comment: Without getting out my ruler to test anything: 1. you need better DC offset removal. 2. I don't think it's either; with slightly improved phase recovery, you might see this clearer, but my standard guess for these kinds of signals is OQPSK.

Comment: @MarcusMüller [OQPSK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Offset_QPSK_(OQPSK)) Wikipedia article, for those of us that didn't know what that meant. :-)

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II LOL! Would an FFT spectrogram of the signal be better?

Comment: Spectogram and/or constellation plot would probably be more useful, yeah.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Yeah I've been a bit stingy about the signal information... my bad. I've added FFT and constellation visualisations with details to the original question :)